# Making a Platform in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make my platform game and don't know how to make the player not go through platforms. I'm very new to Python and Pygame so some help would be very appreciated. So far I've added animations, a background, and a jump mechanic. I mainly followed a guide but also added some things in on my own.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]
bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')
platform = pygame.image.load('platform.png')

x = 50
y = 400
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5
platform_x = 250
platform_y = 320

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0
platform_pos = 320





def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount

    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkCount = 0
    win.blit(platform, (platform_x,platform_y))

    pygame.display.update()


run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - vel - width:
        x += vel
        left = False
        right = True

    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        walkCount = 0

    if not isJump:
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            left = False
            right = False
            walkCount = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False






    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: uses `pygame.Sprite` or at least [pygame.Rect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep position and size of platform and player (and any other object) and then you can check [player.rect.colliderect(platform.rect)](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to check collision of player and platform.

Comment: see [1.4 Platformer examples](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=pl#section_38_4) on [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php)

Comment: "how to make the player not go through platforms". What you've just described in general is 2D collision engine, which is not something pygame provides for you. It does provide some basic helpers like `Rect.colliderect`, however this only *detects* collision, it doesn't actually *resolve* it in any way, which you will want to do to have a playable game. Also keep in mind that pygame's `Rect` only allows integer values for position and dimensions which might not be desirable for your game (it becomes harder to move things along odd angles)

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this is to create the platforms as pygame rectangles, `self.platform = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, w)`. Then I create a hitbox around the player with e.g. a rectangle similar to before: `self.player_hitbox = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, w)`.

Then you check collisions with the 2 by using the code `if self.player_hitbox.colliderect(self.platform)` and do what you want with that information.